# Change color of an image drawn on an HTML5 canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, grayscale

I've got this image here: [image]

How can I change it's entire color to a user-define rgb value?

In other words given an image in grayscale, how do I switch it back to color, with the color being any rgb value.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to change color of image which is being downloaded like "src=http://i.stack.imgur.com/bWA6V.png"

Comment: @AvinashT., once it's drawn to the canvas with drawImage(), the canvas can be changed to affect the color of the image.

Comment: Thanks @Ramin for information.....can you provide any link about it?

Comment: @AvinashT., if I could then I wouldn't need to ask, but http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/ provides hints to achieving something like what I want.

Comment: @Rikonator, see above comment.

Comment: @Ramin, you are quite right on the track. Bitwise ORing the user defined RGB value with the RGB values of the image data should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Rikonator's comment the solution is as follows:

```
function changeColor(img, r, g, b) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.width = img.width;
    c.height = img.height;
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4)
    {
        imgData.data[i]= r | imgData.data[i];
        imgData.data[i+1]= g | imgData.data[i+1];
        imgData.data[i+2]= b | imgData.data[i+2];
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
    return c;
},
```